Sticky bit on /tmp in container causing MPI code to hang
First of all, great job on singularity. It has been very useful so far.  I have a rather detailed question concerning a problem we encountered recently with a project using a CentOS 7 container, MPI 1.95/2.5, and a proprietary application that I did not write (hence, I am having some difficulty building a minimal working example).  We are using singularity 3.8.4 (we would like to upgrade but cannot right now). I will describe the problem and our temporary solution in the hopes that someone more knowledgeable than I will see something I have missed.
First the case where it does not work:

1a) sudo singularity build centos.sif docker://centos:7
2a) sudo singularity build -s centos_s centos.sif
     prompt> ls -ld /tmp     
     drwxrwxrwt. 20 root root 520 May 18 11:21 /tmp
     
     prompt> ls -ld ./centos_s/tmp   
     drwxrwxrwt. 20 root root 520 May 18 11:21 ./centos_s/tmp
     
3a) singularity shell centos_s
4a) Singularity> ls -ld /tmp     
     drwxrwxrwt. 20 root root 520 May 18 11:21 /tmp

5a) While still inside the container execute the code, temporary files
   are created in /tmp (bind mounted to the host /tmp) but never
   deleted. The process simply never terminates.

Now the case where it does work:


1b) sudo singularity build centos.sif docker://centos:7

     Executed as an unprivileged user:
     
2b) singularity build -s centos_s centos.sif 
     prompt> ls -ld /tmp     
     drwxrwxrwt. 20 root root 520 May 18 11:21 /tmp

     Note the absence of the sticky bit:

     prompt> ls -ld ./centos_s/tmp   
     drwxrwxrwx. 20 user group 520 May 18 11:21 ./centos_s/tmp
     
3b) singularity shell centos_s

     Singularity always correctly sets the sticky bit inside the container:
     
4b) Singularity> ls -ld /tmp     
    drwxrwxrwt. 20 root root 520 May 18 11:21 /tmp

5b) While still inside the container execute the code, temporary files
   are created in /tmp (bind mounted to the host /tmp), after the
   computation is complete, the process terminates correctly.

We have verified that manually unsetting the sticky bit in 4a above via sudo chmod o-t causes the first case to work correctly.  We have been unable to recreate the problem with another code using MPI.  However, we note that in both cases the sticky bit is set inside the container. The only difference is whether or not the sticky bit is set on /tmp inside the sandbox prior to using it as a container.  It is unclear how the code running inside the container experiences a different environment in each case (as evidenced by the difference in behavior). Building SIF files from each of the sandboxes yields the same behavior.
Also, we don't know how to cause the permission difference to happen during the original SIF build. Using chmod o-t in %post unsets the sticky bit on the host system (bad).  I would welcome any insight or suggestions.
I tried many combinations of build - the key to success/failure is that if the sticky bit is set on /tmp in the image prior to instantiating the container, there is somehow a difference in the container that affects the running process.
